# Swagger: Required @OA\PathItem() not found

Tags: php, yii2, swagger

I'm using light/yii2-swagger and have next annotations:
main Api Controller:

```
/**
 * @package app\controllers\api
 *
 * @OA\Info(title="Project API", version="1.0")
 *
 */
class ApiController extends Controller
```

and first method

```
/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *     path="/api/index",
 *     @OA\Response(response="200", description="Get default action")
 * )
 * @return array
 */
public function actionIndex()
```

it's worked for php7.4 but for php8.2 I receive an error:

```
[error][yii\base\ErrorException:512] yii\base\ErrorException: Required @OA\PathItem() not found in /var/www/project/vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Loggers/DefaultLogger.php:31
```

Comment: Which version are you using of `light/yii2-swagger`, does it supports PHP 8.2 compatibility?

Comment: @Avnee.Angel 3.0.3 version. it's just a wrapper for base library zircote/swagger-php. The last is supports, yes

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `composer require doctrine/annotations`